# Atmosphere framework: How to call Post method of Meteor pubsub from java program

Tags: java, servlets, atmosphere

I created Atmosphere Meteor Pubsub base on java HttpServlet. I published it on specific server.
Then, I want call to post method of Meteor pubsub.
How to do this?
example: I published meteor pubsub on address: 192.168.x.xx:Port/meteor-pubsub. Remain code java to call post method, I write on client

```
  @Override
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException {
    // Create a Meteor
    Meteor m = Meteor.build(req);

    // Log all events on the console, including WebSocket events.
    m.addListener(new WebSocketEventListenerAdapter());

    res.setContentType("text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1");

    Broadcaster b = lookupBroadcaster(req.getPathInfo());
    m.setBroadcaster(b);

    m.suspend(-1);
}

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException {
    Broadcaster b = lookupBroadcaster(req.getPathInfo());

    String message = req.getReader().readLine();

    if (message != null && message.indexOf("message") != -1) {
        b.broadcast(message.substring("message=".length()));
    }
}

Broadcaster lookupBroadcaster(String pathInfo) {
    String[] decodedPath = pathInfo.split("/");
    Broadcaster b;
    if (decodedPath.length > 0) {
        b = BroadcasterFactory.getDefault().lookup(decodedPath[decodedPath.length - 1], true);
    } else {
        b = BroadcasterFactory.getDefault().lookup("/", true);
    }
    return b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like RESTClient:

http://restclient.net/

Just choose POST on the Method drop down and write the body you want to use. For Atmosphere you can send JSON formatted messages.